# How to assign multiple variables at once in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multiple-assignment

Is there any way to perform multiple assignment in JavaScript like this:

```
var a, b = "one", "two";
```

which would be equivalent to this:

```
var a = "one";
var b = "two";
```

Comment: If you want;

var a = "one", b = "two";

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In ES6 you can do it this way:

```
var [a, b] = ["one", "two"];
```

The above code is ES6 notation and is called array destructuring/object destructuring (if it's an object).

You provide the array on the right-hand side of the expression and you have comma-separated variables surrounded by square brackets on the left-hand side.

The first variable maps to the first array value and so on.

Comment: please add some more description to it, so that the answer is fully understandable

Comment: If you are unsure about the technical term that you used here, then read and add it in your answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Its destructuring we can use array destructuring since we are talking about arrays

Comment: `var [a, b] = [1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: I'd remove the "object destructuring" part since it's a totally different syntax than the one presented, this may confuse beginners

Comment: Will this incur any overhead from constructing the right-side array? Or are interpreters smart enough to have a fast path when the right side is an array literal?

Answer (score 12):

While you cannot do `var a, b = "one", "two";`, and get them assigned to each variable in the respective order, **you can do**:
`var a, b;` to **initialize these variables** as `undefined`.

You can also do `var a, b = 'foo';` to assign b to 'foo', while initializing 'a' as `undefined`.

```
var a, b;

> a
--> undefined
> b
--> undefined
> var d, e;

> e
--> undefined

> f 
--> Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined

> var c, g = 'foo';

> c
--> undefined
> g
--> "foo"
```

### Object destructuring

looks like:

```
const user = {
  id: 42,
  is_verified: true
};

const {id, is_verified} = user;

console.log(id); // 42
console.log(is_verified); // true
```

You will also see this in JavaScript to **[import members of a module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)**:

> Import multiple exports from module. This inserts both foo and bar into the current scope.

```
import {foo, bar} from '/modules/my-module.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't absolutely married to the idea of the values being at the end of the statement, this works:

```
var a = "one", b = "two";
```

If you want to assign to variables that have already been declared, you can use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to make it a one-liner.

```
a = "ONE", b = "TWO";
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to extend Ryan's answer - particularly when it comes to **for** loops.  Normally one might write a **for** loop as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

As many contend, the interpretive nature of JS causes **arr.length** to be reevaluated on every loop - causing performance loss on large loops (depending on the nature of the upper-bound, e.g., a **function**).  When performance is paramount, they suggest iterating backward:

```
for (var i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

However, this approach will cause problems when order is relevant - not to mention being uncommon notation and unclear.  To get around this problem, you can construct it thusly:

```
for (var i = 0, z = arr.length; i < z; i++) {
```

While not as succinct as a standard loop, it performs better whilest being *easier* to read than a reverse loop.

Answer (score -13):

No you can not do this way. Javascript doesn't support this type of declaration

Comment: Except that [it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: I seems you live in ice age of `JS` in ES6 you can use [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)