# How to assign value to a value string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, google-chrome-extension, return-value

I want to assign value to a value string. Sample as below written in javascript

var q="e";
[q]='hio';

e should have value of 'hio'

[JavaScript: Assign a value to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519782/javascript-assign-a-value-to-a-string)

the above link solves the problem. But using eval is not right approach. So I am looking for better approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign multiple variables at once in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411834/how-to-assign-multiple-variables-at-once-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an object:

```js
var myObj = {};
var q = "e";
myObj[q] = "hio";

console.log(myObj.e);
```

Comment: I got this. Rather than creating an object do we have any other clean way?

Comment: Not as written, in your example.  Do you have additional context?

Comment: `[q]='hio'` - has a specific meaning already in Javascript.  It means, assume the right hand side is an array, take the first element, and store it in q.

Comment: I want to take two values. One heading like "Website" and assign second value to it like "www.google.com" .

Comment: That’s commonly called a “key/value pair”, where the key is website and the value is google.  Search for “store key value pair in javascript” if you’d like to get some other ideas.